# How to find the nearest multiple of 16 to my given number n

Tags: multiplicative-function

If I'm given any random $n$ number. What would the algorithm be to find the closest number (that is higher) and a multiple of 16.

Example $55$

Closest number would be $64$

Because
$16*4=64$

Not
$16*3=48$ because its smaller than $55$.

Comment: What is the answer for $n=24?$

Comment: @RossMillikan This would fail my computation. This questions pertains to AES encryption block sizes. They need to be a multiple of 16. So if I had 55bytes I would have to go to the next nearest multiple that is higher then n. Thus failing my requirement

Comment: @RossMillikan: as it is mentioned in OP, the number has to be higher than $n$ - and the closest higher multiple of $16$ is defined uniquely.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As you are surely trying to do this in a computer program, try the following C expression:  $(x|15)+1$. This will always increase, even if $x$ is already a multiple of $16$.

Or try $((x-1)|15)+1$ if you *don't* want to increase the number if it is already a multiple of $16$.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the response! Pretty clever

Comment: Would you mind expanding on why does this work / how did you arrive at this solution

Comment: I am trying to find the multiple just below the given number. So that of the given number is 55, answer would be 48. Any help?

Comment: @nr5 Given that this technique always gives us either the current multiple or the next highest, you can simply subtract the multiple from the result (and use `max` to ensure the result stays positive). In your example, ( ( x - 1 ) | 15 ) + 1 = 64, 64 - 16 = 48, max( 0, 48 ) = 48. The complete algorithm, where x is the value and m is the multiple, would be: `max( 0, ( ( ( x - 1 ) | ( m - 1 ) ) + 1 ) - m )`.

Comment: This doesn't work when I change the multiple to 30. When I do this (100|29) + 1. I get 126, but it should be 120. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For get it. @Beejor answer helped me. I have to round X to the nearest multiple of M first.

Comment: This method is not true for other divisors. Consider x = 1000, m = 3. (1000|(3-1))+1 == 1003.

Comment: ` (x+15) & -16` uses 2 cpu instructions instead of 3, see my answer below.

Answer (score 12):

Use $16\lceil\frac{n}{16}\rceil$ to find the smallest multiple of $16$ not smaller than $n$, where the ceiling function $\lceil x\rceil$ denotes the smallest integer not smaller than $x$.

Use $16\lfloor\frac{n}{16}\rfloor+16$ to find the smallest multiple of $16$ larger than $n$, where the floor function $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the largest integer not larger than $x$.

Comment: This will most likely be my solution as soon as I can figure out how to turn it into C code

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745074/fast-ceiling-of-an-integer-division-in-c-c) to see how to implement ceiling of integer division in C.

Comment: How do you find largest multiple of 16 *not* larger than $n$?

Comment: @David `n - n%16`

Answer (score 10):

A summary of some of the other code, plus a few related items.

#### Find the nearest multiple of M

For a given number X:

```
( x - ( x % m ) )
```

*At or above* a given number X*:

```
( ( x - 1 ) | ( m - 1 ) ) + 1
```

*Below* a given number X*:

```
max( 0, ( ( x - 1 ) | ( m - 1 ) ) + 1 - m )
```

#### Test if X is a multiple of M

```
( x % m == 0 )
```

#### Round X to the nearest multiple of M

Standard rounding:

```
( m == 0 ) ? x : floor( ( x / m ) + 0.5 ) * m
```

*Down to the nearest multiple* (floor, toward -inf):

```
( m == 0 ) ? x : floor( x / m ) * m
```

*Up to the nearest multiple* (ceil, toward +inf):

```
( m == 0 ) ? x : ceil( x / m ) * m
```

<sub>**Legend:** C-like syntax: `|` bitwise OR, `%` modulo, `x?y:z` ternary ("if x then y else z"), `==` comparison.</sub>
<sub>* Generalized for any 2.</sub>
<sub>**More Info:** [math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798899](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798899)</sub>

Comment: I just wanted to add that when using the "Round X to the nearest multiple of M" option. If you remove the 0.5 you will always get the nearest lower number. To get the nearest higher number replace 0.5 with 1.

Comment: @DonnyV. Thanks! I've added your notes to the post. You can also force rounding to the next multiple (one over/under the nearest) like `floor( ( x / m ) + 1 ) * m` or `floor( ( x / m ) - 1 ) * m`, respectively.

Comment: This bitwise OR method does not work when _M_ is not a power of 2 according to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3491658/185886.

Comment: Update: I corrected my answer based on feedback. Apparently the bitwise OR method only works if the multiple is a power of 2. If anyone wants to add the non-generalized-for-2 cases for under/over, please feel free. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you are expressing the number in binary format, you could throw out the last 4 bits and add one and multiply by 16.  This does assume that given a multiple of 16, the number desired is strictly higher.  If in the case where n is a multiple of 16 the answer should be n, then you'd have to check first if the last 4 bits are all zero.

So, in the case of 55 which is 110111 in base 2, this would then becomes 11 in base 2 which is 3 and then adding one gives 4 which times 16 produces 64.

---

There are [Bitshift operators in C](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/bitshift.html) that could be used so you could have a function that takes in a parameter then performs the following series of operations(using Rn's suggestion):

```
int a;
a = n-1;
a = a >> 4; /* which is the same as dividing by 16. */
a = a + 1;
return a << 4; /* which is the same as multiplying by 16 */
```

Comment: Without needing any checks, you can do: subtract one, right shift by four, add one, left shift by four. This works for multiples of $16$ too.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Using `&` as [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND), let `a = n & 15`, then `n - a + ((a+15) & 16)` is what you are looking for (it can be generalized for any $2^k$).

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This was very informative

Comment: Unless there's some advantage to doing it with AND, using OR seems to yield the same result but with less ops/complexity. For example, where N = number, X = multiple: `( ( N - 1 ) | ( X - 1 ) ) + 1` (vs) `N - ( N & ( X - 1 ) ) + ( ( N & ( X - 1 ) ) + ( X - 1 ) ) & X )`.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers and comments saying that the bitwise or approach works in the general case are wrong.

Consider $x = 1000, m = 3$

```
( 1000 | (3-1) ) + 1 == 1003
1003 % 3 != 0
```

This method works in the general case while keeping us type stable (i.e. no need for float division):

```
x - x % m
```

Comment: Nobody is claiming that the bitwise OR works in the general case – it does, however, always work when $m$ is a power of $2$.

Comment: At the time of writing, there is an answer that starts: "To summarize some of the other code, plus a few related items. Find the nearest multiple of M, at or above a given number X"

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3056363/185886) is the one.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Hagen of `((−1)|15)+1` uses a -, |, and + operation; however,
I use the following:

```
  (x+15) & -16
```

This form uses only a + and an & operation, everything else is a constant.