# What is the function for "round n to the nearest m"?

Tags: rounding-unit

Where $n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $m \in \mathbb{R}$, what is the function $f(n, m)$ that can achieve rounding behavior of money where the smallest denomination is not an power of ten?

For instance, if a 5¢ coin is the smallest denomination (like in Canada):

- $f(1.02, 0.05) = 1.00$
- $f(1.03, 0.05) = 1.05$
- $f(1.29, 0.05) = 1.30$
- $f(1.30, 0.05) = 1.30$

Or if $20 is the cutoff:

- $f(9.99, 20) = 0$
- $f(10, 20) = 20$
- $f(39.99, 20) = 40$
- $f(40, 20) = 40$

Comment: Also, if you could help me tag this, it'd be much appreciated! ^^

Comment: Nitpick.  Obviously such a function exists because you just described it and given any two values we'll have output.  What you mean is not does such a function exists, but can such a function be formulaically defined simply.

Comment: @fleablood Fixed! Thanks for recognizing it was a nitpick, too :P

Comment: It's interesting that three answers used the floor function, but none thought to use any version of the round-nearest function.

Comment: @Hurkyl if you have an alternative in mind, do share!

Comment: @Hurkyl I suspect that’s because floor and ceiling are well-defined and there is standard mathematical notation for them. Round-nearest could mean a number of different things — e.g. does 0.5 round up or down? How about -0.5? To be rigorous, you’d normally end up writing the exact variant of round-nearest that you mean as an expression involving floor and/or ceiling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you familiar with the floor function? For $x \in\mathbb{R}$, $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$. That is, there exists an integer $n$ such that $n \leq x <n+1$, and we define $\lfloor x \rfloor =n$. So the floor function rounds to integers, though not to the nearest integer, as, say, $\lfloor 0.9\rfloor = 0$. We can remedy this by taking $f(x)=\lfloor x+0.5\rfloor$. Then $f$ rounds $x$ to the nearest integer to $x$ (rounding $0.5$ up to $1$, etc.).

If you want to round by larger increments, you can scale the input before and after putting it into the floor function. For example, say we want to round **$127$** to the tens digit. Then we first have to scale **$127$** down by a factor of $10$, round to the ones digit, and scale it back up: $$\left\lfloor \frac{127}{10}\right\rfloor\cdot 10=\lfloor 12.7\rfloor\cdot 10=12\cdot 10=120.$$ If we want to round to the *nearest* ten, then again we need to add $0.5$ inside the floor: $$\left\lfloor \frac{127}{10}+0.5\right\rfloor \cdot 10=\lfloor 12.7+0.5\rfloor \cdot 10=\lfloor 13.2\rfloor \cdot 10=13\cdot 10=130.$$

Hopefully you see that the formula you want is
$$f(n,m)=\left\lfloor \frac{n}{m}+0.5\right\rfloor \cdot m.$$

Comment: These all come to the same conclusion, and it works wonderfully for me, but this one says it in a way I understand best. I'm accepting this one but voting them all up!

Comment: to be noted that rounding "half up" (as suggested in this answer) carries some tiny, but possibly not negligible, amount of bias (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking)

Comment: @Federico how could that be counteracted?

Comment: @Supuhstar the wiki article offers some unbiased alternatives, up to you to use your favourite. Your context will also dictate if it makes sense thinking about the problem.

Comment: @Federico would I just replace the "plus .5 and floor" part whole-cloth?

Comment: @Supuhstar Have you seen the wikipedia examples? Is there something not clear? I also repeat, in the 5 cent scenario, this is a non-issue, as you will never have a price ending with 2.5 cents (half cents are not used).

Comment: @Federico you will if you're the one calculating taxes and discounts ;)

Answer (score 7):

Well, as with all things in math, if you need such a function, there's nothing stopping you from saying $f(n,m)$ is $n$ rounded to the nearest $m$, where the higher option is chosen for $n$ precisely between two consecutive multiples of $m$. If you need this a lot, it's easier to read than having a formula each time you invoke this.

However, one can build this out of the floor function, where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is defined as the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$. So $\lfloor .5 \rfloor = 0$ for instance. Then, you have
$$f(m,n)=m\left\lfloor \frac{n}m+\frac{1}2\right\rfloor.$$
This just works by taking the function $\lfloor x + 1/2\rfloor$, which rounds to the nearest integer (with half-integers rounding up), and appropriately scaling.

Comment: Would it be ok to only add .49 to have half-integers round down, or is there a mathematically better way of doing that?

Comment: @DarkNeuron You can subtract $\frac{1}2$ and take the ceiling instead to have half-integers round down instead (where the ceiling $\lceil x\rceil$ is the least integer greater than or equal to $x$ - i.e. the function that rounds up to the next integer).

Answer (score 4):

You didn't indicate what you wanted to do with negative values.  The below rounds toward the nearest denominated value.  There are other choices.

Let $a$ be the amount and $g$ be the minimum denomination.  Your $f$ is $$  f(a,g) = g\left\lfloor \frac{a}{g} + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor  $$
where the "$\lfloor$" and "$\rfloor$" indicate the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).